# Can't redirect output to /var/lib/varlibfile, but I can copy a varlibfile to /var/lib

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script which is running as root, it's supposed to store it's cache file (only modified by the script) at /var/lib/varlibfile. However the script does not seem to create the file, and my investigation led me to this:

```
$ sudo echo "something" >/var/lib/varlibfile
bash: /var/lib/varlibfile: Permission denied
$ sudo echo "something" >varlibfile
$ sudo cp varlibfile /var/lib/
```

In other words, I am able to create a file called varlibfile at /var/lib, but I'm not allowed to create it using redirection. Only file copy works. It seems very strange to me and I would like to use redirection directly to the intended file instead of creating it somewhere else and then copying it.

Some extra information:

```
$ ls -ld /var
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 2009-03-02 14:47 /var
$ ls -ld /var/lib
drwxr-xr-x 51 root root 4096 2009-05-16 19:25 /var/lib
$ ls -la /var/lib/ | head
total 204
drwxr-xr-x  51 root          root          4096 2009-05-16 19:25 .
drwxr-xr-x  14 root          root          4096 2009-03-02 14:47 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root          root          4096 2009-03-02 14:22 acpi-support
drwxr-xr-x   2 root          root          4096 2009-03-02 14:39 alsa
drwxr-xr-x   2 root          root          4096 2009-05-14 14:42 apparmor
drwxr-xr-x   6 root          root          4096 2009-05-14 14:42 apt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root          root          4096 2008-04-04 11:56 aptitude
drwxr-xr-x   2 root          root          4096 2008-07-02 12:58 aspell
drwxr-xr-x   2 avahi-autoipd avahi-autoipd 4096 2009-03-05 16:42 avahi-autoipd
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening? And how to solve the problem, ideally I want to write /var/lib/varfile directly without any previous creation at another location.

Comment: Is this running on a linux system with SELinux enabled?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What

```
$ sudo echo something >/var/lib/varlibfile
```

does, is pipe the output of "`sudo echo something`" to the file. So the file write operation is done as the current user, who doesn't have permission to write in `/var/lib`.

Try something like

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo something >/var/lib/varlibfile"
```

or

```
$ echo something | sudo tee /var/lib/varlibfile
```

Comment: +1 for that. Some people really seem to forget that it's the shell doing the redirections, not the program they start :)

Comment: Yes, like me! :-) At least me.knowledge++ so hopefully I'll remember it from now on.